# IE jumping to top when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

How can i get this to work.....I have a page that has a bunch of items for sale on and you tick a checkbox to make a selection, but when doing so specific in IE it jumps to the top of the page although the selection is made.

There is some jquery in there too

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#submit').click(function(){

  checkValues = '';
  $('input[name="checked"]:checked').each(function(){
  checkValues+=$(this).val()+",\n\n";
  });
  //console.log(checkValues);
  //this is to remove the extra comma , at the end of the string
  checkValues = checkValues.substring(0,(checkValues.length-1));
  $("input[name='checkedValues']").val(checkValues);

  $('#form1').submit();

  });

});
```

So how can this be fixed ?

Comment: Can you show us your form markup? Ta!

Comment: Try using "return false" at the end of your function.

Comment: Does it jump when you tick the checkbox? Or does it jump when you click the submit button?

Comment: When checkbox is ticked

Comment: Just a little help with your checkValues usage. You should use an array to store them, not a string.

Comment: var checkValues = '';   checkValues.push($(this).val());  $("input[name='checkedValues']").val(checkValues.join(","));  It's just a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

When you sumbit a form it will reload the form, So it will move to the top of the page.
if this is a ASP.NET 
try

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

[Maintain scroll position after postbacks in ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/archive/2007/09/07/maintain-scroll-position-after-postbacks-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

Comment: This is a common problem when submitting a form that many devs don't understand. A classic post to a server causes the entire page to be reloaded and since the content is not the exact same the browser has to assume the page is different and does not maintain the position. If you submit via AJAX the page is not posted and your position does not change, since the markup never changes. It is also a more efficient use of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this

```
$('#form1').submit();
```

and write

```
return false;
```

instead of this.

Your code should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#submit').click(function(){

  checkValues = '';
  $('input[name="checked"]:checked').each(function(){
  checkValues+=$(this).val()+",\n\n";
  });
  //console.log(checkValues);
  //this is to remove the extra comma , at the end of the string
  checkValues = checkValues.substring(0,(checkValues.length-1));
  $("input[name='checkedValues']").val(checkValues);

  return false;

  });

});
```

Comment: like so: $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#submit').click(function(){
  
      checkValues = '';
      $('input[name="checked"]:checked').each(function(){
      checkValues+=$(this).val()+",\n\n";
      });
      //console.log(checkValues);
      //this is to remove the extra comma , at the end of the string
      checkValues = checkValues.substring(0,(checkValues.length-1));
      $("input[name='checkedValues']").val(checkValues);
    
      $('#form1').submit();

      return false;
      
    });


  });

Comment: anyone?

 0 down vote accept
 

tried

return false;

but to no avail!

Comment: You should also remove $('#form1').submit(); from you code and add retrun false; instead of this. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#submit').click(function(){
      checkValues = '';
      $('input[name="checked"]:checked').each(function(){
          checkValues+=$(this).val()+",\n\n";
      });

      //console.log(checkValues);
      //this is to remove the extra comma , at the end of the string
      checkValues = checkValues.substring(0,(checkValues.length-1));
      $("input[name='checkedValues']").val(checkValues);

      $('#form1').submit();
  });

});
```

Makes it a little easier to read... this all seems fine, what't the action on your form submit Sounds to me like the problem might be in that...

Comment: There's no action on the form.

Comment: then does it jump to the top with a '#' appended to the current URL? Also, if there's no action on the form, why call $("#form1").submit() is did you create a custom script for the submit?

Comment: Not really a custom script is theere something like ('form').submit() then to submit the data?

Comment: $("#form1").submit() will execute the submit function. If no action is placed this will most likely jump to '#' relative your URL... if you replace $("#form1").submit(); with return false; you should be ok